# nsstring utf8: how can I extract the encoded string?

Tags: iphone, utf-8, nsstring

```
name = "Turai L\U00c3\U00a1szl\U00c3\U00b3";
```

How can I get a proper utf8 encoded string out of it?
I get the name above from a NSDictionary* userContent and extract it:

```
NSString* name = [[userContent objectForKey:@"u"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

but the UITable does not display the characters correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[userContent objectForKey:@"u"] objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

should do the job.

Comment: Warning on using this line!